# Left adjoint of an embedding

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Let R be be an embedding functor from C to D, that is R is injective-on-objects and faithful, and let L be its left adjoint, is there some property of L, and a good name for it, which R being an embedding induces via the adjunction?

Comment: If your functor $R$ is fully faithful, rather than just faithful, these situations are called [reflective subcategories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflective+subcategory). An adjunction is a reflection just when the left adjoint is a dense functor.

Answer (score 0):

It implies that any choice of counit $\epsilon$ is epimorphic. For arrows $f,g:a\to b$, $f\epsilon=g\epsilon$ iff $\epsilon LR(f)=\epsilon LR(g)$ iff $R(f)=R(g)$ and as $R$ is faithful that’s iff $f=g$. In fact we see $R$ is faithful iff the counit is always an epimorphism. But note we didn’t need injectivity on objects.